# Does locking a table locks other tables in case they have a view defined on them in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three tables :

1. ImportBatch
2. PatientChartImages
3. PatientChartBatchMapping  (this table has foreign key to both ImportBatch and PatientChartImages)

I have an un-indexed view defined selecting records from 3 tables. I am explictly locking PatientChartImages table to generate blocking scenerios of production database by following command

```
begin transaction
update PatientChartImages set imagesequence=imagesequence
--Commit transaction
```

Above query locks PatientChartImages table. Also, following query times out :

```
select * from ImportBatch where importbatchid=@importbatchid
```

When i drop the view and follow the same process, ImportBatch query does not time out. Can anybody explain this behaviour. Is this by design or am i doing something crazy?

Comment: If there is no relation b/w those 2 tables then it's something else which is causing the timeout. You can use the stored procedure `sp_who` and `sp_who2` to see who is holding the lock or blocking.

Comment: [sp_whoisactive](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2011/04/27/who-is-active-v11-00-a-month-of-activity-monitoring-part-27-of-30.aspx) is much better than the built-ins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view alone will not cause such behavior. But an indexed view definitely will. Or a foreign key constraint on imagesequence if one exists.